# Given a finite dimensional assocative commutative algebra $A$, what are the properties of annihilators of elements in A?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\mathrm{Ann}(x) = \{ a | ax = 0 \}$ denote the annihilator of elements in $A$. It is easy to prove that this is a linear subspace of $A$, that $\mathrm{Ann}(a) \cap \mathrm{Ann}(b) \leq \mathrm{Ann}(a+b)$, and that $\mathrm{Ann}(a) \cup \mathrm{Ann}(b) \leq \mathrm{Ann}(ab)$.

Specifically, I would like to know whether or not either $\mathrm{Ann}(a) \cup \mathrm{Ann}(b) = \mathrm{Ann}(ab)$ or $\mathrm{Ann}(a) \cap \mathrm{Ann}(b) = \mathrm{Ann}(a+b)$ in general. I can't figure out a way to prove these, but I can't think of any counter-examples either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inclusion $\operatorname{Ann}(a)\cup\operatorname{Ann}(b)\subseteq\operatorname{Ann}(ab)$ is almost trivial, but the converse is not true (e.g. $A=\mathbb{R}^2$ with usual structure, $a=(1,0)$, $b=(0,1)$).

Similarly, $\operatorname{Ann}(a)\cap\operatorname{Ann}(b)\subseteq\operatorname{Ann}(a+b)$ is trivial, but the converse is also not true (take $a=-b$ with nontrivial annihilators. You use $\mathbb{R}^2$, as a ring, seen as an algebra over itself).